# One of setGitDir or setWorkTree must be called eclipse oxygeb gradle

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I am getting the following error when importing the gradle project into eclipse oxygen. I am not getting any error when importing the same project in Idea Intellij

Can you please help me here, if I need to configure any thing on eclipse.

```
Loading Gradle project preview failed due to an error in the referenced Gradle build.
Could not fetch model of type 'GradleBuild' using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.11-all.zip'.

Build file 'C:\harry\test\blog-microservice\build.gradle' line: 29
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'blog-microservice'.
Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.myblog.dig.gradle.versioning']
Could not create an instance of type com.myblog.dig.gradle.versioning.VersioningPluginExtension_Decorated.
One of setGitDir or setWorkTree must be called.
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not fetch model of type 'GradleBuild' using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.11-all.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:51)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultModelBuilder.get(DefaultModelBuilder.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.ConnectionAwareLauncherProxy.invokeRun(ConnectionAwareLauncherProxy.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.ConnectionAwareLauncherProxy.invoke(ConnectionAwareLauncherProxy.java:160)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy30.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider$2.get(DefaultModelProvider.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider$3.call(DefaultModelProvider.java:142)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4724)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3522)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2315)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2278)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2193)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3932)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4721)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider.getFromCache(DefaultModelProvider.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider.executeOperation(DefaultModelProvider.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider.executeModelBuilder(DefaultModelProvider.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider.fetchModel(DefaultModelProvider.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider.fetchGradleBuild(DefaultModelProvider.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.projectimport.ProjectPreviewJob.fetchGradleBuildStructure(ProjectPreviewJob.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.projectimport.ProjectPreviewJob.runToolingApiJobInWorkspace(ProjectPreviewJob.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiWorkspaceJob$1.run(ToolingApiWorkspaceJob.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiInvoker.invoke(ToolingApiInvoker.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiWorkspaceJob.runInWorkspace(ToolingApiWorkspaceJob.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Build file 'C:\harry\test\blog-microservice\build.gradle' line: 29
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'blog-microservice'.
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:74)
    at org.gradle.initialization.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:47)
    at org.gradle.initialization.StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.transform(StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:101)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.getBuildAnalysis(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:87)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.configure(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:102)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:48)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:58)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'blog-microservice'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:93)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$2.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:150)
    at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:72)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:155)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:25)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:521)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:92)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:42)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$2.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:125)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:122)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException: Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.myblog.dig.gradle.versioning']
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:153)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.apply(DefaultPluginManager.java:112)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyType(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:112)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.access$200(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$3.run(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.execute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:135)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractPluginAware.apply(AbstractPluginAware.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.plugins.PluginAware$apply.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectScript.apply(ProjectScript.groovy:35)
    at org.gradle.api.Script$apply$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at build_65hajkpwvusee6pmmicvts9rs.run(C:\harry\test\blog-microservice\build.gradle:29)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:91)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.reflect.ObjectInstantiationException: Could not create an instance of type com.myblog.dig.gradle.versioning.VersioningPluginExtension_Decorated.
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.DirectInstantiator.newInstance(DirectInstantiator.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.ClassGeneratorBackedInstantiator.newInstance(ClassGeneratorBackedInstantiator.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultConvention.create(DefaultConvention.java:106)
    at com.myblog.dig.gradle.versioning.VersioningPlugin.apply(VersioningPlugin.groovy:36)
    at com.myblog.dig.gradle.versioning.VersioningPlugin.apply(VersioningPlugin.groovy)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ImperativeOnlyPluginApplicator.applyImperative(ImperativeOnlyPluginApplicator.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.RuleBasedPluginApplicator.applyImperative(RuleBasedPluginApplicator.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:137)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: One of setGitDir or setWorkTree must be called.
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.BaseRepositoryBuilder.requireGitDirOrWorkTree(BaseRepositoryBuilder.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.BaseRepositoryBuilder.setup(BaseRepositoryBuilder.java:554)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.storage.file.FileRepositoryBuilder.build(FileRepositoryBuilder.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.storage.file.FileRepositoryBuilder$build.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.ajoberstar.grgit.operation.OpenOp.call(OpenOp.groovy:95)
    at org.ajoberstar.grgit.operation.OpenOp.call(OpenOp.groovy)
    at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.ajoberstar.grgit.util.OpSyntaxUtil.tryOp(OpSyntaxUtil.groovy:45)
    at org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit.open(Grgit.groovy:202)
    at org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit$open.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.myblog.dig.gradle.versioning.VersioningPluginExtension.setRoot(VersioningPlugin.groovy:50)
    at com.myblog.dig.gradle.versioning.VersioningPluginExtension_Decorated.setRoot(Unknown Source)
    at com.myblog.dig.gradle.versioning.VersioningPluginExtension_Decorated$setRoot.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at com.myblog.dig.gradle.versioning.VersioningPluginExtension.<init>(VersioningPlugin.groovy:55)
    at com.myblog.dig.gradle.versioning.VersioningPluginExtension_Decorated.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.DirectInstantiator.newInstance(DirectInstantiator.java:49)
    ... 78 more
```

Answer (score 1):

When you build a project through `gradle`, and get the error message `One of setGitDir or setWorkTree must be called`, that normally means, no `git metadata` was found for a project that already had `git` set up. This could be that you downloaded the project as a `.zip`. To fix it just clone the project either through the GUI or git `bash` like below:

> git clone your-project-url